# Avocado tree - multiple indications, not sure what is the issue

Tags: avocado

We have an avocado which used to produce fruits but last year it didn't produce any.

I tried to compare the leaf condition with other cases but there are similarities to different cases, leaves have brown ends, other are dark green, other yellowish.

Could you please advise.

[image][image][image]

Comment: To me, it seems large nutrient deficiency. Did you ever fertilize it? Other possibilities (salt or weedkillers, e.g. from a neighbor road).